# How to install LTS version of nodejs via homebrew

Tags: node.js, homebrew

When I run `brew install node` it install `v6.7.0 Current` but I want **LTS** version which is at the time of this writing `v4.6.0 LTS`. Which commands I need to issue to install **LTS** version of Node via Homebrew.

Comment: Why Homebrew and not [the official installer](https://nodejs.org/en/)?

Comment: Because it requires `sudo` and I prefer to install and manage packages via package manager.

Comment: Fair enough (although you don't need `sudo` if you set the permission correctly, just like with Homebrew), although I see a lot of Node issues flying by here on SO that are related to Homebrew installs. Just so you know. In any case, `6.9.1` is now LTS.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use
`brew install node@4`, `brew install node@6`, or `brew install node@8`
command to install LTS version of Node via Homebrew.

If another version of Node is already installed, you should uninstall it first to avoid conflicts.

Also note that LTS versions of node (e.g. node@10) are keg-only and must either be linked with --force (`brew link --force node@10`) or you need to add the binary to your path by running:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: finally I want to add something. I recommend that you close the terminal window after doing everything. or test it by opening a new tab and typing `node -v` because often this command does not show the correct version.

Comment: Seems to work, for node 12 LTS I had to do `brew install node@12 && brew link --force --overwrite node@12` and restart my terminal.

Comment: Perfect! In fact, I have just realized that it is documented as _Caveats_ after installing `node@16`: `If you need to have node@16 first in your PATH, run: echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@16/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 13):

You can always look up LTS and stable versions from node releases page and also look at homebrew formulae [here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/node).
It shows how u can install stable version vs other versions.
For example right now, `brew install node@10` will install LTS version 10.16.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (Node version manager) to install multiple node versions (LTS, Current, etc.) and use them as per project dependencies.

Install `nvm`:

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Install Node LTS node version:

```
nvm install --lts
```

Install node v14: (mention node version to install that specific version)

```
nvm install 14
```

Install current Node version

```
nvm install node
```

Now, that you've installed bunch of Node versions. You can set anyone to be default.
Set LTS as your default node version:

```
nvm use --lts
```

Comment: Even though the question itself is related to brew, my main goal was to install the LTS version. Using nvm solved the issue. Why installing with brew is so confusing?!?!?

Comment: install NVM like here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. works on Mac Mini M2/Songoma 14.1.1